# SQL Server Dynamic SQL passing in a DateTime2 to use the index to seek?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have this stored procedure that get a page of results based on the CreatedDate, this works really well, it seeks using the index on the CreatedDate so doesn't scan previous rows, e.g. as I get further through the pages it should continue to seek to the next page and pull out the next *n* (10 in this case) rows.

The stored proc looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPageOfMultipartDataFeedItems]
    @NumberOfItems INT, 
    @FromCreatedDate DATETIME2(7) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DataKey, FeedData, CreatedDate
    FROM MultipartDataFeed
    WHERE (@FromCreatedDate IS NULL OR CreatedDate > @FromCreatedDate)
    AND IsActive = 1
    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @NumberOfItems ROWS ONLY
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)
END
```

And the execution plan like this

[image]

This is great but I wanted to get rid of the **OPTION(RECOMPILE)** and use dynamic SQL, which I thought would work but if I use dynamic SQL as shown below it no longer uses the **seek** and **scan**s the previous pages which is not going to be as fast! as this will have millions of rows in it. Can I do this with Dynamic SQL? You can see that this example had read 30 rows instead of the expected 10 like the one with OPTION(RECOMPILE).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPageOfMultipartDataFeedItems]
    @NumberOfItems INT, 
    @FromCreatedDate DATETIME2(7) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @StringToExecute NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @StringToExecute = N'/* GetPageOfMultipartDataFeedItems */
        SELECT DataKey, FeedData, CreatedDate
        FROM MultipartDataFeed
        WHERE (@FromCreatedDate IS NULL OR CreatedDate > @FromCreatedDate)
        AND IsActive = 1
        ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @NumberOfItems ROWS ONLY
    ';

    EXEC sp_executesql @StringToExecute, 
        N'@NumberOfItems INT, 
        @FromCreatedDate DATETIME2(7) = NULL',
        @NumberOfItems, @FromCreatedDate;
END
```

[image]

Comment: There's nothing dynamic about your dynamic query though; the same query is run every time. The point of a dynamic statement is that it creates a statement that differs depending on the parameters. If you simply run the same literal query each time you don't have a dynamic statement, all you're doing is deferring the validation of the query.

Comment: So are you saying keep the OPTION(RECOMPILE) in?

Comment: As an aside, `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY` is more succinctly written as `SELECT TOP(x)`. No need to make it more complicated if you're not going to vary offsets (and I suggest you don't, as `OFFSET`/`FETCH` optimizes very poorly for larger values of `OFFSET`).

Comment: Honestly, for the query you have, I doubt that the overhead of generating a plan each time the query is run very costly. If it were higher complexity, and you knew that the plan required a lot of overhead to generate, sure, but the above query doesn't suggest it is such a query.

Comment: Ok thanks both, appreciate the input

Answer (score 0):

Using `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` allows the optimizer to inspect parameters and variables during each run and generate a plan specifically for the provided values.  The current dynamic SQL run will generate one plan that must must work for any set of parameters.  It will be parameter sniffed on the first run as to whether it optimizes for the general case (`@FromCreatedDate IS NULL`) or the specific case (`CreatedDate > @FromCreatedDate`).

The way to use dynamic SQL to replace the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is to dynamically construct your WHERE clause based on the parameter input.

```
DECLARE @StringToExecute NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @StringToExecute = N'/* GetPageOfMultipartDataFeedItems */
    SELECT DataKey, FeedData, CreatedDate
    FROM MultipartDataFeed
    WHERE IsActive = 1
      ' + CASE WHEN @FromCreatedDate IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE 'AND CreatedDate > @FromCreatedDate' 
      END + '
    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @NumberOfItems ROWS ONLY
';
```

This will generate separate query text for both the general and specific cases.  Therefore it will generated two separate optimized plans.

Comment: This is still not the same thing as `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, however -- for the case where `@FromCreatedDate` is not `NULL`, you will still get one cached plan based on the first value supplied for `@FromCreatedDate`. If you really wanted to split plans like this, a simpler way to achieve it would be with an `IF` on static queries (and admittedly some copy-pasting, but that's par for the course in T-SQL).

Comment: Yes, it is not exactly the same as `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, but the question was asking how to use dynamic SQL and still get a seek.  Using an IF and two static queries is only a small-scale solution.  This dynamic SQL method will be much easier to support when there are many optional parameters in the query.

Comment: I'd recommend [Erland Sommarskog's article on the matter](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) if the OP is really interested in scaling this up -- for the original query this is definitely superfluous.

Comment: Agreed, that is a very good article.